# "Notice: Undefined index" Error when calling php script from QT Application

Tags: php, api, qt, http, networking

This is my 1 line php code;

```
<?php
echo $_POST['api']; ?>
```

And this is my QT Application to call the php script;

```
QUrl url("http://*****.com/id.php");
QNetworkRequest request(url);

request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QUrlQuery params;
params.addQueryItem("api", "test");
networkClients->post(request, params.query().toUtf8());
```

[and this is the notice from PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txY6Y.png)

These lines were working seamless on my previous hosting provider. I moved my stuff to hostinger. Now i can't send data using POST request on my application ($_POST['api'] returns nothing, echo writes nothing). GET request works fine. Also i tested it on reqbin and it worked, while application doesn't.

Comment: Did you submit a form or send post request? You can suppress undefined index with `@$_POST['api']`. But it will not return anything until you send a POST Request.

Comment: It's a post request with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header. I am not trying to hide the error. Because there is no logical explanation of problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with the QT, but the above error stats that the post request with the param name api, is not received. Its clearly mean that the piece of code of QT is not sending POST request with param name api properly.

Answer (score 0):

The **QUrlQuery** adds params to the url.  Which means they have to be received using a **GET**

```php
<?php
echo $_GET['api']; ?>
```

However, it is always advisable to check if the value is null.

```php
<?php
if isset ($_GET['api'])
  {echo $_GET['api'];}
else
  {echo 'Not found';}
?>
```

**POST** can only be used if you are using a form and and a button or an input of type button submits or posts the form.

Comment: Same code works on my other hosting/website, but not working on hostinger's service?